# Only one session login RD WEB Acess

Tags: windows, remote, session, application

Now I created RD Web Access (RDWA) in windows server 2008 R2 everything is work well. 
I need your help, I have a problem

1. Customer A use user A in PC A ( user created in windows server 2008 r2) login in RDWA ex: https://demo.local/rdweb. and run programs
2. Customer A go to another pc (PC B) also login by use User A access webpage https://demo.local/rdweb. and run programs. Now programs in PC A is disconnect and Programs is continue show in PC B.
3. I want if user A login first another user using the same user can’t login or have a notification “ Another user of your computer is currently using this connection.  This user must disconnect before you can log on.”

Important: I already found notification in source of rd web C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\Pages\en-US\login.aspx. 
please focus   bWorkspaceDisconnected = false but it’s not work if I login one user in the same time ??? how make it work for my section

****I will explain for you. User A: Login in PC A at 9:22 AM and now he's using. Another people use user A login in PC B in 9:25 AM. I want the people login in time 9:25 Am can't login because user A already login ( 9:22 AM) and now he using** People login after exist user login before will not login for useing. That's my hope please help me. Thank you so much**

Comment: Sorry, but your edit doesn't make sense.  I can't understand what you're asking... feel free to try again, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Server Manager -> Roles -> Remote Desktop Services -> RD Session host configuration -> Edit Settings -> Restrict each user to a single session = NO

Comment: Thank you so much. But that's not my problem. I only want. When user already login in. If have any person also use User A login in another pc. They can't login because user A already use. Please help me !!!

Comment: I think that it is not possible, your best bet is to give them sepparate accounts.